# Python - How to check the location of the server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to start a proxy server with google app engine python because I want to check if a certain site works in different location. For example, app engine is blocked in China, but doing a reverse proxy might be difficult when it comes to using other webapp2 lib like mail and cron.

Before using other server services like aws, I'm trying to create a proxy with app engine  first to see the concepts behind creating a proxy.

What do we have to modify in order for website to detect the server location instead of the user? How do we check the location of the server programmatically in python or google app engine? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  In addition the question is vague.  What do you mean by the location of the server.  You can only choose europe and us deployment.

Comment: Okay, let me try to improve my question then.

Comment: Is it reasonable to guess that when you say location you mean IP address?

Comment: Well, yeah. This is true too. But I'm still trying to understand how firewalls like the great wall of China works. If we can create a server in like China or in the States and opening websites that's only available within that country. I thought that would be a solution.  Say hulu.com, my current location doesn't allow me to view it because of region restrictions. So if I build a server in the States, and view hulu.com from the server, that might be a working solution. Same way in China, I want to try to create a server outside China that can view sites on google app engine.

Answer (score 1):

A) GAE servers are created in European or American data centres currently, as Tim already noted.

B) You can't reliably check the "location" by IP address of a server.

There are services available, such as: http://www.iplocation.net/ but they can never be 100% accurate.

And you can get a pre-built proxy server, e.g: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/proxy-with-google-app-engine/